# importing a csv but in a csv if comma in cell, then import move evrythng after comma to the next cell

Tags: apex, visualforce

i m importing a csv through apex but in a csv if a comma is in a cell, then the import will move everything after the comma to the next cell. Each comma shifts the data by one cell.
i want that if their is a comma in a cell the whole word should remain in that i.e "a,c,,,b,," this whole word remain in a cell.....

this is my code plz help.....

```
public class importvalidate3 {
public Blob csvFileBody{get;set;}
public string csvAsString{get;set;}
public string csvFileName;
public boolean validatefile=false;
public String[] csvFileLines{get;set;}
public String csvFileLines1;

public String[] csvFileLin{get;set;}
public List<account> acclist{get;set;}
public integer i;
public integer j=1;
public list<integer> i1;
public importvalidate3(){


    csvFileLines = new String[]{};
    i1 = new List<Integer>();
    }

public void importCSVFile(){
       try{
           //csvFileName = csvFileBody.filename();
           string[] csvRecordData;
           csvAsString = csvFileBody.toString();
          /* if(csvAsString.containsAny('""'))
           {
          //string b=a.substringAfter('"')+a.substringBefore('"');
            string b=csvAsString.substringBetween('"');
            system.debug('true b--->'+b);
            }*/
           system.debug('csvAsString--->'+csvAsString);
           csvFileLines = csvAsString.split('\n');

           system.debug('csvFileLines--->'+csvFileLines);

           for(i=1;i<csvFileLines.size();i++){

            system.debug('csvFileLines size is'+csvFileLines.size());
            system.debug('csvFileLines with i'+ csvFileLines[i]+i);

          /* if(csvFileLines[i].containsAny('""'))
           {
           system.debug('csvFileLines[i]--->'+csvFileLines[i]);
         //csvFileLines[i]=csvFileLines[i].substringBefore('"')+(csvFileLines[i].substringBetween('"')).trim()+csvFileLines[i].substringAfterLast('"');
          // csvFileLines[1]=(csvFileLines[i].substringBefore('"')).trim();
           //system.debug('hiiiiiiiiiiii-->'+csvFileLines[i].substringBefore('"'));
             csvFileLines[i]= csvFileLines[i].replaceAll('"','DBQT');
           system.debug(' csvFileLines[i]--->--'+ csvFileLines[i]);


           //csvFileLines[2]=csvFileLines[i].substringBetween('DBQT');
           //system.debug('csvFileLines[2]--->--'+ csvFileLines[2]);

           csvFileLines[3]=csvFileLines[i].substringAfter('DBQT');
           system.debug('csvFileLines[3]--->--'+ csvFileLines[3]);
           //system.debug('csvFileLines1--->'+csvFileLines[i].substringAfterLast('"'));
           system.debug('hiiiiiiiiiiii');


           }*/


            csvRecordData = csvFileLines1.split(',');
            system.debug('csvRecordData--->'+csvRecordData);


            string datatype= csvRecordData[0].trim();
            system.debug('datatype--->'+datatype);

            string fieldlabel=csvRecordData[1].trim();
            system.debug('fieldlabel--->'+fieldlabel);
            string length=csvRecordData[2].trim();
            system.debug('length--->'+length);

            string dec=(csvRecordData[3].trim());
            system.debug('dec--->'+dec);

            String req=csvRecordData[4].trim();
            system.debug('req--->'+req);

                string uni=csvRecordData[5].trim();
                string ext=csvRecordData[6].trim();
                Matcher isnumbers = Pattern.Compile('^[0-9]+$').matcher(length);
                Matcher decimalisnumber = Pattern.Compile('^[0-9]+$').matcher(dec);
                system.debug('### ' + datatype);
                i1.clear();
                if(datatype!='')
                {
                    if(datatype=='text')
                    {
                        if(!((string.isnotblank(fieldlabel))&&(string.isBlank(dec)&& string.isnotblank(length)&&(isnumbers.matches()))&&((req.equalsIgnoreCase('TRUE')||req.equalsIgnoreCase('FALSE')||req.equalsIgnoreCase('0')||req.equalsIgnoreCase('1'))&&(uni.equalsIgnoreCase('TRUE')||uni.equalsIgnoreCase('FALSE')||uni.equalsIgnoreCase('0')||uni.equalsIgnoreCase('1'))&&(ext.equalsIgnoreCase('TRUE')||ext.equalsIgnoreCase('FALSE')||ext.equalsIgnoreCase('0')||ext.equalsIgnoreCase('1')))))
                        {
                        i1.add(i);
                        system.debug('text datatype is internally wrong'+i1);
                        }
                    }
                    else if(datatype=='Number')
                    {
                        system.debug('this is number datatype');
                        if(!((string.isnotblank(fieldlabel))&&(((string.isnotBlank(dec))&&(decimalisnumber.matches()))&&((string.isnotblank(length))&&(isnumbers.matches())))&&(req.equalsIgnoreCase('TRUE')||req.equalsIgnoreCase('FALSE')||req.equalsIgnoreCase('0')||req.equalsIgnoreCase('1'))&&(uni.equalsIgnoreCase('TRUE')||uni.equalsIgnoreCase('FALSE')||uni.equalsIgnoreCase('0')||uni.equalsIgnoreCase('1'))&&(ext.equalsIgnoreCase('TRUE')||ext.equalsIgnoreCase('FALSE')||ext.equalsIgnoreCase('0')||ext.equalsIgnoreCase('1'))))
                        {
                        i1.add(i);
                        system.debug('number datatype is internally wrong'+i1);
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                       i1.add(i);
                       system.debug('datatype is wrong'+i1);
                    }

                }
            else
            { 
            i1.add(i);
            system.debug('fill datatype'+i1);
            }   
        }


    }
    catch(exception e)
    {
    system.debug(e);
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using csv (comma separated values) files, be **certain** to use double quote to enclose each field.

For example:

This csv file has 4 columns, "LastName", "FirstName", "Title", "HomePhone"

This will load correctly into Contact Object:

"Smith,  SR.","Joe","Chief Cook","555-555-1212"

This file **will NOT load** correctly into Contact Object:

Smith,  SR.,Joe,Chief Cook,555-555-1212

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, good first answer!

Answer (score 1):

You may be better off starting from this [Parse a CSV with APEX](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Code_Samples#Parse_a_CSV_with_APEX) code sample. It avoids the expense of character by character processing by starting with some `replaceAll` calls so that embedded commas can be handled appropriately. And has presumably been tested by a number of people.

You can add your own logic as required, or perhaps better take the results from that code and apply your logic in a second pass over the data.